# jQuery document ready fail to load with <embed src=""> in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, document-ready

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('document.ready');
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src=""></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

it fail to load document ready in ie9 .
if I add someting in  src , it works.

Comment: run the URL in your IE and see if you are able to load it . then the problem is with IE only